# How do I create a new dataframe column based on conditions of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new dataframe column `surv` with `lts` and `non_lts` labels, where for all values of the `clin["OS_MONTHS"]` column in the `clin` dataframe, label the value as `lts` if value is <= 2*12, else label it as `non_lts`.

The criteria is:

```
import pandas as pd

non_lts = clin[(clin["OS_MONTHS"].astype(float)<= 2*12)]
lts = clin[~clin.isin(non_lts)].dropna()
```

but I want it as a dataframe `surv`.

My attempt:

```
# Survival info
def survival(clin):
    if clin["OS_MONTHS"].astype(float)<= 2*12:
        val = "lts"
    else:
        val = "non-lts"
    return val

clin['SURV'] = clin.apply(survival, axis=1)
```

Desired output `surv`

|  | surv |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | lts |
| 1 | non_lts |

Answer (score 1):

You may try this one using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```py
clin.loc[clin['OS_MONTHS'] <= 2*12, 'surv'] = 'lts' 
clin.loc[clin['OS_MONTHS'] > 2*12, 'surv'] = 'non_lts'
```